# How to reinitialize highlight.js?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, highlightjs

My website is generating some content dynamically, so I have to somehow launch the [highlight.js](http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/) plugin again after loading it.

This code is used to launch the highlighter:

```
hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
```

I tried to do something like `hljs.initHighlighting();` to do this again but it does not work.

Comment: Are you using Turbolinks? Because if you are, I'm pretty sure that's the delimiter. I can't get the two to work together (something to do with the hljs's asynchronousity). Turbolinks is infamous for causing problems and complications.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You must set called to false first:

```
hljs.initHighlighting.called = false;
hljs.initHighlighting();
```

Comment: Isn't this what `initHighlightingOnLoad()` is for?

Comment: Nice, but this solution has problem it reset highlighted object cursor to 0,0.
If you try to invoke on a contenteditable element you fill find yourself writing backward.

Answer (score 6):

You can reinitialize all of the codeblocks like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('pre code').each(function(i, e) {hljs.highlightBlock(e)});
});
```

or if you have a div with an ID of myBlock, you can do this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#myBlock').each(function(i, e) {hljs.highlightBlock(e)});
});
```

Comment: Does Sergey's answer not apply it for all the blocks?

Comment: Also there's no reason to believe the questioner is using jQuery, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I use this in my react application to update the components when the state is changed. it can be called in componentDidUpdate() with the follow code.

var blocks = document.querySelectorAll('pre code:not(.hljs)');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(blocks, hljs.highlightBlock);

Answer (score 0):

i hope this could solve your problem..
you have to use

```
hljs.highlightAll()
```

since, hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad() is deprecated since version 10.6.

if you're using react, you could apply at componentdidMount..

```
  useEffect(() => {
    hljs.highlightAll()
  }, []);
```

or, if another framework, please call that function when page loaded.
more: https://highlightjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

Answer (score 0):

### If you using react hooks please follow this;

I get the solution by integrate [react-highlight](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-highlight).

You can use `innerHtml` to true on the property.

```js
import Highlight from "react-highlight"
import "highlight.js/styles/gradient-dark.css"; // import style on the root file
import JSONViewer from "./JSONViewer"

<Highlight innerHTML className="w-full">
  <JSONViewer content={yourContentHere} />
</Highlight>
```

Set `innerHTML=true` to highlight multiple code snippets at a time. This is especially usefull if html with multiple code snippets is generated from preprocesser tools like markdown.

> Warning: If innerHTML is set to true, make sure the html generated
> with code snippets is from trusted source.

### Trying to forcing it on useEffect?

Using `hljs.registerLanguage("json", json);` or `hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();` will getting a problem by rerendering react. It's not recall when using dependency but `useEffect` without dependency like this it works.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad(); // it works, but bad for performance because will call every single time re-rendering.
})

useEffect(() => {
  hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad(); // it doesn't works
}, [])
```