# Highlight code dynamically in React using hljs library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax-highlighting

I fetch code snippets from the server to display.

If I want to display the code, I attach the node to DOM. If there is no code to display, I remove the node from DOM.

I'm using [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/) to highlight the code.

**To highlight**:

```
<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
```

But the problem is, it only highlights the code on load as the method name indicates.

So, I need to check and highlight the code.

I guess refreshing the page after every request is not a solution.

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21510365/4859791) SO answer:

```
hljs.initHighlighting.called = false;
hljs.initHighlighting();
```

But I don't see any highlighting.

How can I highlight the code dynamically whenever I want in ReactJS?

Comment: Have you read the documentation?

Comment: @SkrewEverything Yes, but some of the examples are in jQuery and some of them are just docs without any examples. I couldn't figure it out myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dynamically highlight certain nodes(which your code must be between `<code><pre></pre></code>`) in your DOM:

```
hljs.highlightBlock(document.getElementById("codeblock"));
```

Where, `codeblock` is the id of your node. For example,  `<code id=""codeblock><pre></pre></code>`.

What we do here is, we are using `hljs` method to highlight only particular element/node in your DOM.

And you are adding and removing elements from your DOM. So, you need to check if any new element that you are intended to highlight is added or not. And call the above function to highlight the code.

To check for mutations in your DOM, you can use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to a listen to the changes and call the above function to highlight the code.

Note: Don't use `setTimeout()` to poll for changes! It effects performance of the website.

If you find [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) difficult to implement, you can use this awesome library [arrive](https://github.com/uzairfarooq/arrive).

Either download `.min.js` and include it in your browser or Install the npm package of `arrive`:

```
$ npm install -S arrive
```

If you are using through npm, import it in your code like `require("arrive");`

Write a callback function for `arrive`:

```
highlight(){
        if(document.getElementById("codeblock") != null){
            hljs.highlightBlock(document.getElementById("codeblock"));
        }

}
```

To register `arrive`: Call this in your `constructor()`

```
document.arrive("#codeblock", () => this.highlight());
```

It should do the work.

Comment: Thanks. Once again you saved me a lot of time.